# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 128, 128, 1) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a simple binary image classifier.
Initially, my data looked like this

```
X_train.shape:  (1421, 128, 128, 3)
X_test.shape :  (356, 128, 128, 3)
y_train.shape:  (1421,)
y_test.shape :  (356,)
```

tried to reshape data with

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 3)
X_test  = X_test.reshape(-1,  img_size, img_size, 3)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test  = y_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

and result updated to

```
X_train.shape:  (1421, 128, 128, 3)
X_test.shape :  (356, 128, 128, 3)
y_train.shape:  (1421, 1)
y_test.shape :  (356, 1)
```

model

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train[0].shape)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(32),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    patience=10,
    min_delta=0.001,
    restore_best_weights=True,
)

history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    batch_size=512,
    epochs=10,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
    verbose=2
)
```

and got the error

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 128, 128, 1) vs (None, 1))
```

Comment: you need to add a Flatten or GlobalPooling layer inside your network in order to pass to a 2D output

Comment: Your input is 3 channel. Dense does not take input 3 channel. Add a conv layer as input layer to your model. and then flatten to flat it.

Comment: @AhmadAnis Dense can handle dimensions > 2 ... "If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the last axis" (from: https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/)

Comment: Interesting. I did not knew about it. @H R shuvo, where are you compiling the mode? May be you are using wrong loss function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Flatten layer` with `Dense layer`.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                             Flatten(input_shape=(128, 128, 3))),
                             Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                             Dense(32, activation='relu'),
                             Dense(32),
                             Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
                             ])
```

Or can use `convolutional layers` in your model as given below:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

and then compile the model.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```